# Python group and transpose a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
Index   hour    Disconnection
0   8   Key press
1   8   Key press
2   8   Key press
3   8   Key press
4   8   Key press
5   8   Key press
6   8   Abandon
7   8   Abandon
8   8   Abandon
9   8   Key press
10  8   Abandon
11  8   Key press
12  8   Key press
13  8   Key press
14  9   Abandon
15  9   Abandon
16  9   Key press
17  9   Abandon
18  9   Key press
19  9   Key press
20  9   Key press
```

I need to first group by hour and then create 2 columns that will take the values from 'Disconnection' which are Key press or Abandon then count each value per hour interval

the result should look like this:

[image]

Comment: check `crosstab` with margins parameter

Comment: tried this one new_df = pd.pivot_table(df, index = 'hour', columns = 'Disconnection', values = 'Disconnection', aggfunc='count')

Comment: hmm, try `crosstab` if need Totals

Comment: thanks @jezrael i used the crosstab and it works
new_df = pd.crosstab(df.hour, df.Disconnection)